# How to uninstall a service completely from an application in the next upgrade which isn't a major upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am trying to uninstall an installed service that has several components but not able to.
Could anyone please help me with the uninstalling tags too? I did a lot of searches but couldn't run anything successfully.

Just putting ServiceControl tag and removing all the components work? I tried that but didn't work. How do you deal with components and dependencies? Need logic and syntax help.

Below is my code that installs the service in the previous version. Please let me know of the tags that I have to add to remove this.

```
<Directory Id="dirxxx" Name="oldname">
                <!-- oldname service-->
              <Component Id="cmpOldNameService" Guid="bbb"
                  SharedDllRefCount="no" KeyPath="no" NeverOverwrite="no" Permanent="no" Transitive="no"
                  Win64="no" Location="either">
              <RemoveFile Id="ccc" On="uninstall" Name="z.dll"/>
              <File Id="ccc" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.xSource)\OldNameService\a.dll"/>
              <File Id="ddd" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.xSource)\OldNameService\b.dll"/>
              <File Id="eee" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.xSource)\OldNameService\c.dll"/>
              <File Id="fff" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.xSource)\OldNameService\d.dll"/>
              <File Id="ggg" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.xSource)\OldNameService\e.dll"/>
              <File Id="hhh" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.xSource)\OldNameService\f.dll"/>
              <File Id="iii" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.xSource)\OldNameService\g.exe"/>
              <File Id="jjj" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.xSource)\OldNameService\h.dll"/>
              <File Id="kkk" KeyPath="no" Source="$(var.xSource)\OldNameService\i.dll"/>
              <ServiceInstall Id="OldNameService" DisplayName="OldName Service" Name="NewName"
                ErrorControl="normal" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" Description="OldName Service">
                <ServiceConfig DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall="yes"/>
              </ServiceInstall>

              <ServiceControl Id="OldNameServiceControl" Name="NewName"
                Start="install" Stop="uninstall" Remove="uninstall" Wait="no"/>

            </Component>

              <Component Id="lll" Guid="mmm" NeverOverwrite="yes">
                <File Id="nnn" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.xSource)\OldNameService\OldName.exe.config"/>
                <util:XmlFile Id="UpdateOldNamelogFileName"
                              File="[#nnn]"
                              Action="setValue"
                              ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='logFile'[\]]/@value"
                              Value="[ooo]oldname_YYYYMM.log" />
              </Component>



<!--Recovery-Interval needs to be added in both cases new install as well as upgrades-->     


                  <Component Id="qqq" Guid="r-r-r-r-r" NeverOverwrite="yes">
                      <Condition><![CDATA[INSTALDIR <> "" AND NOT REMOVE AND POSTV1 = ""]]></Condition>
                      <CreateFolder /> 

                      <util:XmlConfig Id="RecoveryInterval" Action="create" ElementPath="config/settings" File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config" Node="element" On="install" Name="add" Sequence="1">
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="RecoveryInterval2" ElementId="RecoveryInterval" Name="key" Value="Recovery-Interval" File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config" />
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="RecoveryInterval3" ElementId="RecoveryInterval" Name="value" Value="3600" File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config" />
                      </util:XmlConfig>
                  </Component>

                  <!-- Analytics-->
                  <Component Id="eee" Guid="f-f-f-f-f" NeverOverwrite="yes">
                      <Condition><![CDATA[(INSTALDIR <> "") AND NOT REMOVE]]></Condition>
                      <CreateFolder />                          
                      <!-- Analytics-->
                      <util:XmlConfig Id="EnableAnalytics" Action="create" ElementPath="config/settings" File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config" Node="element" On="install" Name="add" VerifyPath="/config/settings/add[\[]@key='EnableAnalytics'[\]]">
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="EnableAnalytics2" ElementId="EnableAnalytics" Name="key" Value="VEnableAnalytics" File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config" />
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="EnableAnalytics3" ElementId="EnableAnalytics" Name="value" Value="1" File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config" />
                      </util:XmlConfig>

                      <util:XmlConfig Id="AnalyticsTrackingId" Action="create" ElementPath="config/settings" File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config" Node="element" On="install" Name="add" VerifyPath="/config/settings/add[\[]@key='AnalyticsTrackingId'[\]]">
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="AnalyticsTrackingId2" ElementId="AnalyticsTrackingId" Name="key" Value="AnalyticsTrackingId" File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config" />
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="AnalyticsTrackingId3" ElementId="AnalyticsTrackingId" Name="value" Value="YwByAE3eVweXAAcAVwBasBUAAgAMsB0AAwAbzz==" File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config" />
                      </util:XmlConfig>
                  </Component>

                  <!-- Added to handle upgrade scenario for assembly binding redirect for Newtonsoft.json -->
                  <Component Id="cmpNewtonsoftVersionUpgrade" Guid="{a-60CA-d-w-f}" NeverOverwrite="yes">
                      <Condition><![CDATA[(INSTALDIR <> "") AND NOT REMOVE]]></Condition>
                      <CreateFolder/>
                      <util:XmlConfig Id="AddRuntimeElement"
                                      File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                      Action="create" Node="element" Name="runtime" On="install"
                                      ElementPath="configuration"
                                      VerifyPath="/configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[\[]@name='Newtonsoft.Json'[\]]"
                                      Sequence="1" />
                      <util:XmlConfig Id="AddAssemblyBindingElement"
                                      File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                      Action="create" Node="element" Name="assemblyBinding" On="install"  ElementPath="configuration/runtime"
                                      VerifyPath="/configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[\[]@name='Newtonsoft.Json'[\]]"
                                      Sequence="2"/>
                      <util:XmlConfig Id="AddDependentAssemblyElement"
                                      File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                      Action="create" Node="element" Name="dependentAssembly" On="install"
                                      ElementPath="configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding"
                                      VerifyPath="/configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[\[]@name='Newtonsoft.Json'[\]]"
                                      Sequence="3"/>
                      <util:XmlConfig Id="AddAssemblyIdentityElement"
                                      File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                      Action="create" Node="element" Name="assemblyIdentity" On="install"
                                      ElementPath="configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly"
                                      VerifyPath="/configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[\[]@name='Newtonsoft.Json'[\]]"
                                      Sequence="4">
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="AddNameKey"
                                          File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                          ElementId="AddAssemblyIdentityElement" Name="name" Value="Newtonsoft.Json" />
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="AddPublicKeyToken"
                                          File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                          ElementId="AddAssemblyIdentityElement" Name="publicKeyToken" Value="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="AddCulture"
                                          File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                          ElementId="AddAssemblyIdentityElement" Name="culture" Value="neutral" />
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="AddXmlnsOnAssemblyIdentity"
                                          File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                          ElementId="AddAssemblyIdentityElement" Name="xmlns" Value="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
                      </util:XmlConfig>
                      <util:XmlConfig Id="DeleteBindingRedirectElement"
                                      File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                      Action="delete" Node="element" Name="bindingRedirect" On="install"
                                      ElementPath="configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly[\[]assemblyIdentity[\[]@name='Newtonsoft.Json'[\]][\]]"
                                      VerifyPath="/configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly/bindingRedirect[\[]@oldVersion='0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0'[\]]"
                                      Sequence="5" />
                      <util:XmlConfig Id="DeleteBindingRedirectElementoldserviceOnv4"
                                      File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                      Action="delete" Node="element" Name="bindingRedirect" On="install"
                                      ElementPath="configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly[\[]assemblyIdentity[\[]@name='Newtonsoft.Json'[\]][\]]"
                                      VerifyPath="/configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly/bindingRedirect[\[]@oldVersion='0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0'[\]]"
                                      Sequence="6" />
                      <util:XmlConfig Id="AddBindingRedirectElement"
                                      File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                      Action="create" Node="element" Name="bindingRedirect" On="install"
                                      ElementPath="configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly[\[]assemblyIdentity[\[]@name='Newtonsoft.Json'[\]][\]]"
                                      VerifyPath="/configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly/bindingRedirect[\[]@oldVersion='0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0'[\]]"
                                      Sequence="7">
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="AddOldVersionKey"
                                          File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                          ElementId="AddBindingRedirectElement" Name="oldVersion" Value="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" />
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="AddNewVersionKeyS3Uploader"
                                          File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                          ElementId="AddBindingRedirectElement" Name="newVersion" Value="9.0.0.0" />
                          <util:XmlConfig Id="AddXmlnsOnBindingRedirectS3Uploader"
                                          File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                          ElementId="AddBindingRedirectElement" Name="xmlns" Value="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
                      </util:XmlConfig>
                      <util:XmlConfig Id="AddNameSpaceToyElement"
                                      File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                      Action="create" Node="value" Name="xmlns" Value="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" On="install"
                                      ElementPath="/configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding"
                                      Sequence="8" />
                      <util:XmlConfig Id="AddNameSpaceToDependentAssemblyElement"
                                      File="[INSTALDIR]\oldname\OldNameService.exe.config"
                                      Action="create" Node="value" Name="xmlns" Value="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" On="install"
                                      ElementPath="/configuration/runtime/assemblyBinding/dependentAssembly[\[]assemblyIdentity[\[]@name='Newtonsoft.Json'[\]][\]]"
                                      Sequence="9" />

                  </Component>
</Directory>
```

EXAMPLE TRIAL FOR 1 COMPONENT:

```
 <Component Id="cmpoldNameService" Guid="9-kj-4509-ko-B4F7700AFDCE"
                                 SharedDllRefCount="no" KeyPath="no" NeverOverwrite="no" Permanent="no" Transitive="yes"
                                 Win64="no" Location="either">
                          <Condition>FALSE</Condition>
                          <RemoveFolder Id="diytg" On="uninstall"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="ghgj" On="uninstall" Name="a.dll"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="uiu" On="uninstall" Name="b.dll"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="hujhjn" On="uninstall" Name="c.dll"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="okl" On="uninstall" Name="d.dll"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="bbb" On="uninstall" Name="e.dll"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="bbbb" On="uninstall" Name="f.dll"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="kkkl" On="uninstall" Name="g.dll"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="mmmm" On="uninstall" Name="h.dll"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="nnn" On="uninstall" Name="i.exe"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="bboo" On="uninstall" Name="j.dll"/>
                          <RemoveFile Id="ttt" On="uninstall" Name="k.dll"/>

                          <ServiceControl Id="OldNameServiceControl" Name="OldName"
                                          Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Wait="yes"/>

                      </Component>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSI Minor Upgrades can't officially remove components or features.  The workaround (Hack) is to keep the original components but supply them a zero byte file and set the Revaluate attribute (transitive bit in MSI) to true and give it a condition that will always evaluate to false.   This way the Windows Installer transitions this component to not installed and the service is stopped and removed.

You'll have to keep this 0 byte fake component around until you do your next major upgrade.  Then it can be removed.

To be honest, Minor Upgrades are very picky and if you don't already know these rules you might be better served by always doing major upgrades until you do.  Minor upgrades can push you into a corner really hard if you let it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please give a sample code for one of the components. Do I have to include files as well which points to the path as in the new version, those files are removed. So the use case here is that I am renaming the existing service. I tried just renaming and it didn't work so I am uninstalling existing one and installing the renamed one as a new one with new GUIDS.

Comment: You need to provide your wix build a zero byte file by the same name so the component is still valid and compile.  You have to create a new component with new guid for your new service.  It's not being renamed per say but the old one is being removed and the new one added.

Comment: Check my edit. I added a code for one component. Could you verify if this is correct and I have to do that for all components?

Comment: Pretty much although technically someone could pass FALSE=1 ;)  My favorite is to use a private variable like 'Deprecated'

Comment: Like this:  <?define Deprecated="TRUE"?> <Condition>$Deprecated</Condition>

Comment: No. Simply <Condition>Deprecated</Condition>   The original blogger who described this pattern years ago used the condition GotoHell=666.

Comment: PS- in the future each EXE and DLL should be the keyfile of it's own component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152562/discussion-between-atihska-and-christopher-painter).

Comment: So I will still need to define it as <?define Deprecated="TRUE"?>. Right?
Or <Condition>Deprecated=TRUE</Condition>
Also, will I need ServiceInstall Element or just ServiceControl as mentioned is fine? I removed ServiceInstall tag.
And one more thing, if for some components, the file is a keypath, then what's the difference in condition?